# Query column for duplicate from variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to check if a string already exists in a table column. The **column name** is in the form of a string, @language = 'german', **column name** being german.

```
Word.where(@language: string).empty?
```

So I want it to do

```
Word.where(german: string).empty?
```

How can I use @language in the where clause?

Comment: while I like @papirtiger's answer  you could also use interpolation which might be even faster (not planning on benching it) like so `Word.where("#{@language}" => string)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Word.where(Hash[@language, string]).exists?
```

`Hash[@language, string]` is one of those beautiful rubyisms that creates a hash dynamically.

```
irb(main):005:0> @language = 'german'
=> "german"
irb(main):006:0> string = 'kummerspeck'
=> "kummerspeck"
irb(main):007:0> Hash[@language, string]
=> {"german"=>"kummerspeck"}
```

Comment: This method is processing the fastest, so I chose this.

Comment: Don't think so - check my response.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exists?`:

```
Word.exists?(@language => string)
```

The issue you're having is that the syntax `@language: string` actually means `:@language => string`.

Don't think this is going to be slower:

```
require 'benchmark'    
@language = 'english'
string = 'Hello world'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { 100000.times { a = Hash[@language, string] } }
  x.report { 100000.times { a = { @language => string } } }
end
```

prints out

```
    user     system      total        real
0.100000   0.040000   0.140000 (  0.143954)
0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.050434)
```

on my machine.

Interestingly enough, on my machine it looks like .where().exists? is faster than .exists? on its own:

```
require 'benchmark'
column = 'last_name'
value = 'Jones'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { 10000.times { User.exists?(column => value) } }
  x.report { 10000.times { User.where(column => value).exists? } }
end
```

Comment: There is no column language:, Unknown column 'words.language' in ... the column is 'words.german' but can be 'words.chinese' based on the string.

Comment: Ahh, didn't catch that from your description. Updated.

Comment: Good explanation, makes sense. The Hash way is faster in my logs. A lot faster so I'm going to use that.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the benchmark. I tried it with [Benchmark.bmbm](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-bmbm). Surprisingly `"#{@language}" => string` is actually negligibly faster.

Comment: Hope that's within the margin of error, because that makes no sense.

Comment: Weird. I don't get that.

Comment: You have to test the speed using a query, with a table having atleast 10,000 records.

Answer (score 1):

Might vary based on db, dynamic columns not recommended btw

```
Word.where("#{@langauge} IS NULL")
```

Comment: yeah, sometimes its simpler

Comment: This is dangerous depending on where `@language` comes from. i.e. if it's "1=1; DELETE FROM users; --"

Comment: Absolutely, I assume this is a fixed list. And in all the answers the column name can never be null and must always exist in the database. Bonus points for an answer that handles that gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `column_names` return all table column field name

`Word.column_names.include?(@language)`

Comment: Word.column_names is an Array, which include? is undefined

Comment: This answer is half complete - it is a pretty good idea of how to ensure that  the column exists but it does not include the actual query. You could use it like so. `Word.where(Hash[@language, string]).exists? if Word.column_names.include?(@language)`

Comment: or you could use it like..`Word.column_names.include?(@language) && Word.where(Hash[@language, string]).exists?`

Comment: @papirtiger I see, var language is defined in the backend so I am not worried about validation.